# How to prove that $\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4n+2)^2}{(4n+1)(4n+3)}=\sqrt{2}$

Tags: infinite-product

How to prove that $$\displaystyle\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4n+2)^2}{(4n+1)(4n+3)}=\sqrt{2}$$

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Hi ! This look like a homework question : tell us what you've done and where you are stuck so users will give you usefull hints.

Comment: I get (1+1)(1-1/3)(1+1/5)(1-1/7)...

Comment: For those interested, see [Wallis product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) and the related [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite a partial product as

$$\prod_{n=0}^N \frac{(4 n+2)^3 (4 n+4)}{(4 n+1)(4 n+2)(4 n+3) (4 n+4)} = \frac{2^{3 N+3} (2 N+1)!!^3 4^{N+1} (N+1)!}{(4 N+4)!} $$

Use the fact that

$$(2 N+1)!! = \frac{(2 N+1)!}{2^N N!} $$

and

$$M! \approx M^M e^{-M} \sqrt{2 \pi M} \quad (M \to \infty)$$

The rest is careful bookkeeping, and making sure you use the fact that

$$\lim_{M \to \infty} \left ( 1+\frac1{M} \right )^M = e$$

the sought-after result follows.

Comment: And, yes, I did it out.

Comment: A very nice solution indeed.  But why did you initially adjust the product.  Why not just start with $\frac{2^N (2N+1)!!^2}{(4N+3)!!}$ and proceed accordingly?

Comment: @Dr.MV: thanks.  I did no such adjustment.  The fact is that there are $N+1$ terms in the product, so what I wrote is indeed the partial product as stated.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  Another way to ask is as follows:  "Why did you multiply and divide by $(4n+4)(4n+2)$?  One could have written the product as $\frac{2^N(2N+1)!!^2}{(4N+3)!!}$, could one not?  What advantage was there to "massaging" the form (not the substance) of the partial product?  Does that make better sense now?  By the way, I checked out your website.  Most impressive!!

Comment: @Dr.MV: I'm glad you like it.  As to your question, I did not want to deal with $(4 N + 3)!!$.  No other reason.

Comment: Yes it's really cool. And thanks for the reply here. I suppose (4N+3)!! is a bit messy.

Answer (score 3):

From the Weierstrass product for the cosine function we have:
$$ \cos z = \prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}\right) $$
and by taking $z=\frac{\pi}{4}$ it follows that:
$$\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(4n+2)^2}\right)=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
whose LHS is just the reciprocal of our product.

Comment: In general, $~\Gamma(1+x)~\Gamma(1-x)=\dfrac{\pi x}{\sin(\pi x)}~$ and $~\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12+x\bigg)~\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12-x\bigg)=\dfrac\pi{\cos(\pi x)}.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rewrite the infinite product expression in terms of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and then apply Euler's famous [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).