# $\prod\limits_{k=0 \atop 2k+1\ne 0 \bmod n}^\infty \frac{2k+1+(-1)^{\lfloor (2k+1)/n\rfloor}}{2k+1}=\sqrt{n}$ for $n\ge 2$

Tags: infinite-product

I found tasks in an old script. For the following problem I have no idea how to solve.

How can one prove $$\prod\limits_{k=0 \atop 2k+1\ne 0 \bmod n}^\infty \frac{2k+1+(-1)^{\lfloor (2k+1)/n\rfloor}}{2k+1}=\sqrt{n}$$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\ge 2$?

It generalizes
[How to prove that $\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4n+2)^2}{(4n+1)(4n+3)}=\sqrt{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193869/how-to-prove-that-prod-n-0-infty-frac4n224n14n3-sqrt2?rq=1) .

Examples $n=2$ and $n=3$:

$$\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2k+1+(-1)^k}{2k+1}= \frac{2}{1}\frac{2}{3}\frac{6}{5}\frac{6}{7}\frac{10}{9}\frac{10}{11}…=\sqrt{2}$$ 
$$\prod\limits_{k=0 \atop 2k+1\ne 0 \bmod 3}^\infty \frac{2k+1+(-1)^{\lfloor (2k+1)/3\rfloor}}{2k+1}= \frac{2}{1}\frac{4}{5}\frac{8}{7}\frac{10}{11}\frac{14}{13}\frac{16}{17}…=\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: My guess is that it involves a careful rewriting of the problem into a form where you can apply Sterling's approximation. Might be a difficult exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, the first idea is Stirling. But I hope for a more general perspective.

Comment: Using [Euler's definition of the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler.27s_definition),

$$
\Gamma(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!n^t}{\prod_{k=0}^n(t+k)}\;,
$$

we can write

\begin{align}
\pi_m(a,b)
&=
\prod_{j=0}^m(aj+b)
\\
&=
a^{m+1}\prod_{j=0}^m\left(j+\frac ba\right)
\\
&\sim
\frac{a^{m+1}m!m^{b/a}}{\Gamma\left(\frac ba\right)}
\;.
\end{align}

The factors in your products are such that the numerators of these approximations cancel and the limit is determined by the denominators.

Comment: For instance, for $n=4$,

$$
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac18\right) \Gamma\left(\frac38\right)\Gamma\left(\frac58\right)\Gamma \left(\frac78\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac28\right)\Gamma\left(\frac48\right) \Gamma\left(\frac48\right)\Gamma\left(\frac68\right)}=\sqrt4
$$

comes out right, but I don't know how to prove this for general $n$. [This property of the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#Products) might play a role:

$$
\prod_{r=1}^n \Gamma\left(\frac r{n+1}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{n+1}}\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I fear it becomes too complicate. I found an hint, that the creator of the task (the name is not written) used $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{k\pi}{2n}=\sqrt{n}2^{1-n}$ and that this leads to $\sqrt{n}=2^{n-1}\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2kn-1)!}{(2(k-1)n)!((2k-1)n)^{2n-1}}$ . I still don't understand the relationships.

Comment: @joriki : Then it has to work, if I substitute $\sin$ by its product extension (like with the $\Gamma$-function) and exchange the product symbols. - I will see. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literature: Sierpinski Oeuvres Choisies I (page 222-226) 
 http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Sierpinski%20Oeuvres%20Choisies%20I.pdf

Gamma function product: $\displaystyle \Gamma(1+x)=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} m^x/\prod\limits_{k=1}^m \left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)$

or written äquivalent  $\displaystyle m^x/\prod\limits_{k=1}^m \left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right) \sim\Gamma(1+x)$ .

Therefore one get

$(1)$ $\displaystyle m^x\prod\limits_{k=1}^m \frac{k-x}{k}\sim\Gamma(1-x)$

and general

$(2)$ $\displaystyle (nm)^x\prod\limits_{k=1}^{nm} \frac{k-x}{k}\sim\Gamma(1-x)$

for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$.

It’s $\dfrac{nk}{nk-x}\dfrac{k-x}{k} =1+\dfrac{(1-n)x}{nk-x}$ and with $\dfrac{(2)}{(1)}$ follows therefore 
$$ \prod\limits_{k=1}^m\frac{k-x}{k} \prod\limits_{k=1}^{nm}\frac{k}{k-x}     =  
\prod\limits_{k=1}^m \left(\frac{nk}{nk-x}\frac{k-x}{k}\right) \prod\limits_{ k=1 \atop k\ne 0 \bmod n }^{nm}\left(1+\frac{x}{k-x}\right)  $$ $$=
\prod\limits_{k=1}^{nm}\left(1+\frac{x(1-0^{k-n\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\rfloor}n)}{k-x}\right) \sim n^x$$

with $0^0:=1$.

---

With $x:=\frac{1}{2}$ the formula of the question is proofed.