# An infinite product obtained by taking every third term from the Wallis product. Is it new?

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Numerical calculation suggests that
$\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(6n+2)^2}{(6n+1)(6n+3)} = \frac{3^{1/2}}{2^{1/3}}$.

Has this been proven?

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: $\left(\prod_{n=0}^{10^7}\right)^6\approx\frac{27}4-10^{-7}$

Comment: I think the following can help. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193869

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ n $ be a positive integer, we have : \begin{aligned} \frac{\Gamma^{2}\left(k+1+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+1+\frac{1}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(k+1+\frac{1}{2}\right)}&=\frac{\left(6k+2\right)^{2}}{\left(6k+1\right)\left(6k+3\right)}\times\frac{\Gamma^{2}\left(k+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\ \Longrightarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{\Gamma^{2}\left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{7}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}&=\prod_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\left(6k+2\right)^{2}}{\left(6k+1\right)\left(6k+3\right)}}\times\frac{\Gamma^{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} \end{aligned}

Using the [Legendre duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula), we have that : \begin{aligned} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\right)&=\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\\ \iff \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)&=\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\end{aligned}

Multiplying both sides by $ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) $, then using [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula#Known_formula), we get : \begin{aligned} \Gamma^{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\times\frac{\pi}{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}}&=\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\times\frac{\pi}{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}}\\ \iff \Gamma^{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\times 2\pi&=\sqrt[3]{2}\;\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\times\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\\ \iff \ \ \frac{\Gamma^{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}&=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt{3}} \end{aligned}

Thus, for every positive integer $ n $ we have : $$ \prod_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\left(6k+2\right)^{2}}{\left(6k+1\right)\left(6k+3\right)}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\;\Gamma^{2}\left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{2}\;\Gamma\left(n+\frac{7}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)} $$

Using [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Stirling's_formula), we get the Following approximations : \begin{aligned}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)&\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\sqrt{2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right)}\left(\frac{n+\frac{1}{3}}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{3}}\\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{7}{6}\right)&\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\sqrt{2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{6}\right)}\left(\frac{n+\frac{1}{6}}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{6}}\\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)&\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\sqrt{2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{n+\frac{1}{2}}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\end{aligned}

Which lead to the following : $$ \frac{\Gamma^{2}\left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{7}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}1 $$

Thus : $$ \prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\left(6n+2\right)^{2}}{\left(6n+1\right)\left(6n+3\right)}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\left(6k+2\right)^{2}}{\left(6k+1\right)\left(6k+3\right)}}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt[3]{2}} $$

Comment: Beautiful work. This approach can be used to show that if $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ are constants with $a_1+a_2= b_1 + b_2$, then $\prod_{n\ge 0} \frac{(n+a_1)(n+a_2)}{(n+b_1)(n+b_2)}  = \frac{\Gamma(b_1)\Gamma(b_2)}{\Gamma(a_1)\Gamma(a_2)}$. This result is useful for evaluating similar infinite products. It can be extended to $a_1+a_2 +\dots + a_k = b_1 + b_2+\dots + b_k $ for products involving $k$ factors in the numerator/denominator.